# Django ORM, sum of multiple columns

Tags: django, django-orm, django-aggregation

I have a question about how we can filter by SUM of multiple columns.

Example:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    i1 = models.IntegerField()
    i2 = models.IntegerField()
    i3 = models.IntegerField()
```

And I need to filter objects where SUM of i1, i2, i3 is less then 200.
I've tried achive it with:

```
Foo.objects.agregate(i_sum=Sum(i1,i2,i3)).filter(i_sum__lt=200) # error
Foo.objects.agregate(i_sum=Sum([i1,i2,i3])).filter(i_sum__lt=200) # error
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [F()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters), and [with annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations):

```
Foo.objects.annotate(i_sum=F('i1') + F('i2')+ F('i3')).filter(i_sum=200)
```

Comment: thanks, it was really obvious. Sum is some kind of vertical operation but I needed horizontal.

Comment: Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `extra`

```
Foo.objects.extra(where=["i1 + i2 + i3 > 200"])
```