# Calculation sum of two fields to filter entries

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, orm

I have a model class called Foo, with the following fields *start* and *duration*.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    duration = models.DurationField()
```

I want to filter all the entries from the Foo table by checking that the start plus duration is less than a certain time.

Comment: Just to make sure, you're using Mysql like your tag suggest or Postgres ?

Comment: @scharette MySQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django ORM, sum of multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323724/django-orm-sum-of-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to the this with *F expressions*

```
from django.db.models import F
Foo.objects.filter(duration__lt=yourTime - F('start'))
```

You may need to make use of `timedelta`. See more examples [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters)