# Django: Annotate sum on variable number of columns

Tags: python, django, django-annotate

So I've read the annotate columns, and utilizing the F() functions, and I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323724/django-orm-sum-of-multiple-columns/43323971) on how to sum multiple columns. However, I'm working with an EAV style DB, so I'm given a variable list of columns. Consider the example:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    column_a = models.FloatField()
    column_b = models.FloatField()
    column_c = models.FloatField()
    column_d = models.FloatField()
```

**ATTEMPT 1:**

```
columns = {'column_a', 'column_c', 'column_d'}
queryset = DummyModel.objects.annotate(total=Sum([F(column_name) for column_name in columns]))
```

However, a `print(queryset.query)` yields the error `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field`

**ATTEMPT 2:**

```
queryset = DummyModel.objects.annotate(total=ExpressionWrapper(Sum([F(column_name) for column_name in columns]), output_field=FloatField()))
```

This does not yield a compilation error, but the SQL query yields:

```
SELECT "test_model"."column_a", "test_model"."column_c", "test_model"."column_d", SUM([]) AS "total" FROM "test_model"
```

Which is empty. Does anyone have any idea of how to solve this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To figure this out, it helps to picture the table first:

```
column_a | column b | column_c
---------+----------+----------
1        | 2        | 3
4        | 5        | 6
7        | 8        | 9
```

`Sum` is a "vertical" operation; that is, if we wanted the sum of `column_a`, we could do

```
>>> DummyModel.objects.aggregate(total=Sum('column_a'))
{'total': 12}
```

As you can see, this returns `1 + 4 + 7 == 12` -- so you can see why I call it a "vertical" sum. Notice we use `aggregate` rather than `annotate`: `aggregate` is for vertical operators.

If instead we want "horizontal" sum -- the total across a row -- we'd use `F()` and `+`. So to get `column_a + column_b` in each row, we'd use

```
>>> DummyModel.objects.annotate(total=F('column_a') + F('column_b')).values('total')
<QuerySet [{'total': 3}, {'total': 9}, {'total': 15}]>
```

Hopefully you can see why I call this a "horizontal" sum: we're getting a sum of `a` and `b` "horizontally" in each row. And now notice we use `annotate`, which is for horizontal operations.

If the names of the columns aren't known beforehand, you'd need to get tricky and use [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [operator.add](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html#operator.add) to build up an expression:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import add

>>> cols = ['column_b', 'column_c']
>>> expr = reduce(add, (F(col) for col in cols))
>>> DummyModel.objects.annotate(total=expr).values('total')
<QuerySet [{'total': 5}, {'total': 11}, {'total': 17}]>
```

If we want *both* a horizontal and a vertical sum -- i.e. the sum of `column_a` plus the sum of `column_b` -- we need to use `Sum` and `F()`:

```
>>> DummyModel.objects.aggregate(total=Sum(F('column_a') + F('column_b')))
{'total': 27}
```

Notice: `aggregate` rather than annotate, since we're ultimately going with a vertical operation; a `Sum` of rows. Yes, there's a horizontal operation first, but since we ultimately `Sum`, we need `aggregate`.

So, to wrap things up, if the fields are a variable, we need to combine `aggregate`, `Sum`, and the `reduce` trickery from above:

```
>>> cols = ['column_b', 'column_c']
>>> expr = reduce(add, (F(col) for col in cols))
>>> DummyModel.objects.aggregate(total=Sum(expr))
{'total': 33}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm looking for. I can actually go one simpler, and legitimately even use the simple `sum` from python to do a horizontal sum with `F()` to get it working. Using `reduce` would be more generic, but not necessary for the purposes of my use. In any case, no aggregation is needed on my part, it was just a dynamic horizontal summing that was needed. Turns out I was close. Thanks!